# Java VLCJ player, set audio track is not working

Tags: java, media-player, vlcj, audiotrack

I am currently working on java media player that can play `mkv` format. I am using `VLCJ`, everything is working except when I try to change audio track which is not working.

here is the code

```
public class mediaplayer {

    private static JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();

    public mediaplayer() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String vlcPath = "", mediaPath = "";
        File ourfile;

        filechooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        filechooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        ourfile = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
        mediaPath = ourfile.getAbsolutePath();

        EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediacom = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(mediacom);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.setSize(1050, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        MediaPlayer mplayer = mediacom.getMediaPlayer();

        mplayer.playMedia(mediaPath);
        mplayer.setAudioTrack(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In libVLC versions before **vlc 2.0.5** the native API call to set the audio track was bugged.

With the fix in **libVLC 2.0.5**, setting the audio track works reliably but you can not just assume a simple index from **0..N** and you can not assume sequential track numbers - you must enumerate the audio tracks by calling `mediaPlayer.getAudioDescriptions()`. The returned TrackDescription objects contain an audio track identifier that should be used with `mediaPlayer.setAudioTrack()`.

To disable audio, you can select the audio track identifier of the track with a a description of `"Disable"`.

Also be aware that you might not be able to set the audio track immediately after calling `mediaPlayer.playMedia()`. Media is started asynchronously and you may need to wait until the media has actually started and/or has been parsed before the track information is available.

Answer (score 0):

6 years later

The API have grown a lot

If you want to stop or choose an audio track you can use this code snippet and adapt it, the idea is to wait for the player to start using a process then switching to what you need, in my case is the audio disabling

```
new Thread(
                    () -> {
                        try {
                            while(!empc.mediaPlayer().status().isPlaying())Thread.sleep(500);
                            empc.mediaPlayer().audio().trackDescriptions().stream()
                            .filter(td -> td.description().equals("Disable"))
                            .forEach(t -> empc.mediaPlayer().audio().setTrack(t.id()));
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    ).start();
```

**empc** is my media player instance {the embed one for more precision in the player component}